# Array not being updated outside of foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a piece of code that I'm struggling with. I'm still on my first steps so it's entirely possible that some silly mistake is causing this.
I want to turn each first character of each word into uppercase, but for some reason it is not working and I cannot get it figured out.

```
        $split = explode(" ",$string);

        foreach ($split as $word) {

            if (ord($word[0]) >= 97 & ord($word[0]) <= 122){
                $word[0] = chr(ord($word[0]) - 32);              
        }}

        return $string;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: array\_push doesn't seem to save added value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674250/how-to-fix-array-push-doesnt-seem-to-save-added-value)

Comment: You're saving in the current key not in the array as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

You should handle this a little differently.

Let's create our split first:

```
$words = explode(' ', $words_string);
```

Now let's loop through these words and remember their index by using the `$key` param.

```
foreach($words as $index => $word) { //So we remember the key in the array using $k => $v

   $words[$index] = ucfirst($word); //This will uppercase the first letter.

}
```

Comment: Why do you use `foreach` with `ucfirst()` when there is `ucwords()`?

Comment: @MichalHynčica Because he used a foreach and I wasn't sure if his intention was to do more than just ucfirst so i kept it that way and made his code functional.

Comment: Ok, but then you've missed that he is returning the original `$string` instead of imploding the modified array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is explained in the question i've linked.

However in your case the solution is much more simple. You can just use [ucwords()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) function or [mb_convert_case()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) with `MB_CASE_TITLE` if you work with multibyte strings.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides in-built function that help you convert every word's first character to uppercase of the string without exploding and iterating through.

```
ucwords( $string );
```

EDIT: Let us include a sample to help you out what would be the output:

```
echo ucwords("Hi this is just a simple test of converting each word's first charater to uppercase!");
```

will return

```
Hi This Is Just A Simple Test Of Converting Each Word's First Charater To Uppercase!
```